# WebSphere Thread Management

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, websphere, websphere-7

I was looking for configure the thread pool by application instead of profile. Basically, to avoid the  unavailability of threads for most important application that share the profile with application that can run in background.

Is there any configuration thread pools by application instead of profile?

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to use a dedicated thread pool for the critical application.

However in order to achieve that you need to use a separate host-port combination for that particular application.
That is because a web threads pool is associated with a web container transport chain and a transport chain is determined by a host-port pair.